# How to access first element under ListItem or ListItemWrapper

Tags: python, pywinauto

How to access first element under ListItem or ListItemWrapper

Short Example of Code to Demonstrate the Problem

```
display=appNewConnect.AppWindow.child_window(title="Class Properties", control_type="Window").child_window(control_type="List").wrapper_object()

print(display)

Output:

uia_controls.ListViewWrapper - '', ListBox

checking dir(display) and used below methods

print(display.cells())
```

Output:

```
[[<uia_controls.HeaderItemWrapper - 'Display', HeaderItem, -1851307684>,

<uia_controls.HeaderItemWrapper - 'Expression', HeaderItem, 812249353>,

<uia_controls.HeaderItemWrapper - 'Label', HeaderItem, 1553609319>,

<uia_controls.HeaderItemWrapper - 'Scale', HeaderItem, -77800940>],

[<uia_controls.EditWrapper - '', Edit, 271613010>,

<uia_controls.StaticWrapper - 'All features', Static, 1012972976>,

<uia_controls.StaticWrapper - 'All features', Static, -618437283>,

<uia_controls.StaticWrapper - 'All scales', Static, 122922683>]]
```

Getting the second list

```
item = display.get_item(1)

print(item)
```

Output:

```
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - '', ListItem
```

I am trying to click on

`<uia_controls.EditWrapper - '', Edit, 271613010>`

but dir(item) does not list any methods that can be used for accessing the first index

element in ListItem

How to access first element under ListItem or ListItemWrapper

Specifications

Pywinauto version: 0.6.8

Python version and bitness: 3.8.2

Platform and OS: windows 10

Comment: `display.cells()` appears to return something list-like, so what happens if you index it?  i.e. `display.cells()[1][0]`?

Comment: Thanks. this does help to identify the element but still it does not click on it and instead it clicks on the entire ListItem in the middle. I tried double_click_input(coords=(0, 0)) which does the trick. If we have methods under ListItemWrapper maybe a direct click (without co ordinates) on that element might have worked

Comment: Glad you found an answer: if you add one below it will make it easier for the next person who has this problem.  I don't use pywinauto, I'm afraid.